# how the tensorflow call the device?

Tags: tensorflow, device, assign

how the tensorflow call the device? And how the tesorflow assign the task to the device for automatically? Are there interface source code in tensorflow? But I can't find the source code in details.

just like :

with tf.device('/gpu:2'):

a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')

b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')

c = tf.matmul(a, b)

why when we run the with tf.device('/gpu:2'):,the ops(a,b,c) can assign to the gpu:2 for automatically,how can I find the detailed descriptions in the source code of tensorflow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are several parts of the TensorFlow codebase that are relevant to what device is invoked.

1. [`SimplePlacer::Run()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dc6c17797c065796603d9259b2aa57b3c07ff71/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc#L624) will assign a fully-qualified device to every node in a TensorFlow graph.
2. [`Partition()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dc6c17797c065796603d9259b2aa57b3c07ff71/tensorflow/core/graph/graph_partition.cc#L801) will split a graph (in which each node is labelled with a fully-qualified device) into multiple per-device subgraphs.
3. Once an `OpKernel` instance has been created for each of your ops (e.g. [`MatMulOp`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dc6c17797c065796603d9259b2aa57b3c07ff71/tensorflow/core/kernels/matmul_op.cc#L258) for `tf.matmul()`), [`BaseGPUDevice::Compute()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dc6c17797c065796603d9259b2aa57b3c07ff71/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc#L308) is called to invoke that kernel on a particular GPU. This calls [`BaseGPUDevice::ComputeHelper()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dc6c17797c065796603d9259b2aa57b3c07ff71/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc#L337), which obtains a CUDA stream for the computation, and calls `OpKernel::Compute()`.
4. In the `OpKernel::Compute()` method for your kernel (e.g. [`MatMulOp::Compute()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dc6c17797c065796603d9259b2aa57b3c07ff71/tensorflow/core/kernels/matmul_op.cc#L265)), some device-specific code will be invoked to issue the computation on the CUDA stream (e.g. for `MatMulOp`, we [invoke cuBLAS GEMM](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dc6c17797c065796603d9259b2aa57b3c07ff71/tensorflow/core/kernels/matmul_op.cc#L239)). Most invocations on the CUDA stream go via the [`tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dc6c17797c065796603d9259b2aa57b3c07ff71/tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.h#L1167) interface.

Comment: Thank you! But I have a another question:how the tensorflow  put the task really on the hardware to run.If I add a new device: just called it KPU ,the tensorflow can  assign the task to the device for automatically.Or when I use tf.device("/KPU:0"),the ops can be computed by KPU.

Comment: Eventually, TensorFlow will invoke a vendor-provided library (such as cuDNN) or a device driver to issue the computation to the device. Depending on the architecture of your KPU, you may be able to reuse the `tensorflow/stream_executor` framework for issuing this computation via a `stream` (as TensorFlow does for CUDA-supporting GPUs), but the specifics will depend very much on what a KPU actually is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have read the souce codes which are about  tensorflow/stream_executor framework ?What about CPU?And If the tensorflow calls my device to computation, I need to add KPU device driver codes in tensorflow/stream_executor?

Comment: For GPU invocations, the main entry point is [`tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/97c6203bb3f3978ac67920c66b6234ef82051c57/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.h). CPU code is simpler because the kernels run "locally" on the same device (or at least share an address space with the host code), so TensorFlow just uses a threadpool (sometimes via convenient interfaces like [`Shard()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/76b2c0630b850694d0fb3dd0b670b4d9e75d9513/tensorflow/core/util/work_sharder.cc#L23).

Comment: What you will need to do for the "KPU" depends on what kind of device it is, so it's hard to say exactly what you'd need to do. But if its hardware interface is similar to a GPU - that is, if it uses a computation stream with asynchronous callbacks - then you should consider extending the `tensorflow/stream_executor` framework with your device management code.